# Magento 2: Migration using models

Tags: magento2, magento-1, model, migration

I would like to migrate products from magento 1 to magento 2 using core models instead of the migration toolkit provided by magento.

The reason is that the products need A LOT of modification in the process.

What i'd like to do is write a custom script that handles the models from both stores. So my idea was to do this:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$conn = $resource->getConnection();

// pointing to Mage.php from magento 1
require_once('../../www/app/Mage.php');
$app = Mage::app(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product->getId() . "\n";
}
```

This fails because the BP constant has already been defined in magento 2.

```
PHP Notice:  Constant BP already defined in /path/to/old/store/app/Mage.php on line 29
```

Is there a way to use the model api of both magento 1 and magento 2 within one script?